# IE creating duplicate anchors in my Navigation in version 11.0.9600.17280

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

(http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsinc/jvzztgjk/6/)

This is a browser-specific problem which is only occurring in IE. Originally the file was missing the DOCTYPE, which I have inserted since then and even after fixing all of the missing self-close tags in the images on the page, and validating with 0 errors it still occurs. Whats happening in IE is there is another copy of the anchor tag with class="hoverMenu" inserted right above it so in IE Developer Tools (F12) ONE of the navigation buttons looks like this:

```
    <div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul id="navigationMenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="hoverMenu">HOME</a>
                <a href="#" class="hoverMenu">HOME</a>
                <a href="#" class="normalMenu">HOME</a><a href="#" class="hoverMenu">HOME</a><a href="#" class="normalMenu">HOME</a>
           </li>                

        </ul>
    </div>
```

My DOCTYPE is XHTML 1.0 Transitional. Could it be occurring due to how the XHTML standard handles anchors? Also, there is a jquery script that is using addClass for the rollover effect.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#navigationMenu li .normalMenu').each(function(){

            $(this).before($(this).clone().removeClass().addClass('hoverMenu'));

        });

        $('#navigationMenu li').hover(function(){

            $(this).find('.hoverMenu').stop().animate({marginTop:'0px'},200);

        },

        function(){

            $(this).find('.hoverMenu').stop().animate({marginTop:'-25px'},200);

        });

    });
```

Perhaps it is an IE Quircks-Mode related issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks to all in advance -qs

Comment: Your source is working fine in IE... in your fiddle have a look at your html markup!! There is the hoverMenu link already added!

Comment: Thanks, there is only ONE instance of <a href="#" class="hoverMenu"> within the <li>, however, there are TWO instances of it showing up in developer tools (IE or FF). Not sure why? -qs